# Replacing select tag on mobile

Tags: usability, mobile, select

I'm currently using Select2 to replace some filters for a reviews' page. I think for desktop they work really good, having filters and more control over the CSS of it, but my question comes about it when it moves to a responsive viewport: Wouldn't it be more usable to have the native select the browser uses from mobile devices?

I'm not aware of any alternative with a better behavior, if there's any.

Comment: This is more of an implementation question instead of a UX question.  The UX answer is try and design a solution around native controls as much as possible because replacing them with your own is sure to be less responsive and less familiar.

Comment: @DaveAlger Thanks, that helps! I just need more opinions on the use of this kind of replacement feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not perfect, but we're replacing the select tags only if the device DOESN'T support touch support.

The native option picker for iOS and Android is definitely the better solution

Comment: Thanks for you input. What do you use to replace the select?

Comment: We're also using select2

Comment: @MisterOh how did this pan out?